# DynamoDB - Single item vs Multiple item, what is more cost-effective

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-billing

**Approach #1: (Single item)**

Single partition key, with all data included in the item, example:

```
PK: Item#1
object_attribute_1: full json item
object_attribute_2: full json item
object_attribute_3: full json item
object_attribute_4: full json item
```

**Advantages I see**: Less write costs, we write entire item at same time, so the round ups are more effective.

**Disadvantages**: Read costs might be bigger, because there is no option to filter, let's imagine I just need to query object_attribute_2 and not entire item.

**Approach #2: (Multiple items)**

Partition key + sort key combination, example:

```
Item#1:
PK: Object#1
SK: object_attribute_1_SK
object_attribute_1: full json item
```

```
Item#2:
PK: Object#1
SK: object_attribute_2_SK
object_attribute_2: full json item
```

```
Item#3:
PK: Object#1
SK: object_attribute_3_SK
object_attribute_3: full json item
```

```
Item#4:
PK: Object#1
SK: object_attribute_4_SK
object_attribute_4: full json item
```

**Advantages I see**: Can reduce read costs, in situation we only need specific thing, using SK, instead of returning entire object information, returns only what needed, less KB read

**Disadvantages I see**: Might increase write costs?

1 - It's 4 writes for single object (does the writes also depend in query transactions or only KB size?)

2 - If the full json item is less than 1KB, let's say 500b, is rounded up to 1kb , or 1.5kb rounded up to 2kb, etc

Which approach you advise me? I'm thinking well?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's 4 writes for single object (does the writes also depend in query transactions or only KB size?)

DynamoDB has this concept of [WCU (Write Capacity Unit)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html). This can be calculated as such:

```
1 WCU = 1 write of up to 1 KB/s
or
2 WCU = 1 transactional write request up to 1 KB/s
```

So, if you consume `4 WCU`, you either write `4 KB` of data per second using non-transactional write operations or `2 KB` of data using transactional write operations.

> 2 - If the full json item is less than 1KB, let's say 500b, is rounded up to 1kb , or 1.5kb rounded up to 2kb, etc

The WCU/RCU is rounded up, meaning if you write a json document of `1.5 KB` if will cost `2 WCU` with non-transactional write and `4 WCU` for transactional write.

Regarding your approaches, you probably would want to use smaller objects and avoid having consistent reads/transactional write if they are not really necessary.

Also, DynamoDB has [Projection Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html) for retrieving parts of a document. Unfortunately, this does not reduces RCU consumption, as far as I know.

Comment: Hey Ervin, I am looking into projections as it eliminates my advantage of multiple items.  

Edit: it seems doesn't eliminate RCU data :/ "Projection expressions are subject to the same caveats as filter
expressions—they are evaluated after the items are read from the
table and the 1MB limit is reached."